# Question about center of a group/subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ a non abelian group of order $p^aq^b$ where $p,q$ are prime and $p^aq^b$ is not prime. I want to show that $G$ is not simple.

In a proof of my course, they do as following for the case where $|G|=p^a$ with $a\geq 2$. They say that if $Z(G)=G$, then $G$ is abelian, and thus of order a prime, which is a contradiction. I really don't understand why $|G|=p$ (since for example a group of order $p^2$ or $p^3$ is abelian as well.

Comment: They use that the only *simple* abelian groups are those of prime order.

Comment: Simple and abelian implies cyclic of order $p$, a prime.

Comment: This is a well-known result of Burnside, and he proved it using character theory. A purely group-theoretical proof was found eventually, but it is much longer and more difficult than the character theory proof. In any case it does not make any sense to try and do this as an exercise.